# Using python and ncurses, display count down timer and take user input simultaneously

Tags: python, timer, ncurses

I am writing a small python game using ncurses. I want to display a count down timer continuously and also take user input simultaneously.

In main function, I created one thread that displays the countdown timer and then put one loop which takes input from user.

Problem : When the player says "quit" the game doesnt quit, the game ends only after the timer thread count downs till zero. How to kill that timer thread in between ?

Answer (score 1):

Mark your timer thread as daemon, that is set

```
thread.daemon = True
```

(where `thread` is your timer thread object) before calling `thread.start()`.